# Printing using list comprehension

Tags: python

From my Python console

```
>>> numbers = [1,2,3]
>>> [print(x) for x in numbers]
1
2
3
[None, None, None]
```

Why does this print three none's at the end?

Comment: because `print()` is a function in python3 that returns `None`

Comment: The Python interpreter always prints the value of any expression that you enter.  If you changed it to `r = [print(x) for x in numbers]`, you would see that `r` now contains `[None, None, None]`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A list comprehension is not the right tool for the job at hand. It'll always return a *list*, and given that `print()` evaluates to `None`, the list is filled with `None` values. A simple `for` loop works better when we're not interested in creating a list of values, only in evaluating a function with no returned value:

```
for x in numbers:
    print(x)
```

Comment: You can use `for x in numbers: print(x)` if you want it on one line.

Answer (score 47):

You should restructure your loop to send arguments to `print()`:

```
>>> numbers = [1,2,3]
>>> print(*(x for x in numbers), sep='\n')
```

Note that you don't need the explicit generator. Just unpack the `list` itself:

```
>>> numbers = [1,2,3]
>>> print(*numbers, sep='\n')
```

Comment: This is faster than for loops
`toplevel_Search = glob("*.py")
recursive_search = glob("**/*.py",recursive=True)

begin = time.time()
print (*toplevel_Search,sep="\n")
end = time.time()
print("Time taken without a loop: ", end-begin)

begin = time.time()
for i in toplevel_Search: print(i)
end = time.time()
print("Time taken with a loop: ", end-begin)`

Output::
`pathlibDemo.py
main.py
pathlibDemo_COPY.py
globDemo.py
Time taken without a loop:  0.00017619
pathlibDemo.py
main.py
pathlibDemo_COPY.py
globDemo.py
Time taken with a loop:  0.0001959`

Answer (score 7):

`List comprehensions` always return a `list`.

Based on this information, your `print()` statement must wrap the whole list comprehension argument:

```
Numbers = [1, 2, 3]

print([x for x in Numbers])
```

If you want to print items of a list one by one, a for loop is more suitable for this matter.

Answer (score 3):

The `print` function returns `None`. The list comprehension is applying the function to each element of the list (outputting the results), but collecting those `None` objects into the results array. The Python interpreter is printing that array.

Answer (score 3):

[print(x) for x in numbers] is a list without values. so it returns none.
you can simply do the followings:

```
print(*numbers)
```

1 2 3
or

```
for x in numbers:
 print(x)
```

1
2
3

Answer (score 2):

`print` is a function in Python 3, which returns a `None`. Since you are calling it three times, it constructs a list of three `None` elements.

Answer (score 1):

print is a function, it's just like

```
>>>def f(x):
...:   pass
>>>[f(x) for x in numbers]
```

Answer (score 1):

An ugly way of doing this is `_=[print(i) for i in somelist]`
It does work but is not encouraged:)

Answer (score 0):

If this behaviour of the Print function bothers, I suggest you don't use the Print function in the list comprehension, just use the following one-liner which is compact and more Pythonic:

```
>>> [x for x in [1,2,3]]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String Join() method and print the string. For example:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(numbers))
1
2
3
>>> print(', '.join(numbers))
1, 2, 3
>>> print(',\n'.join(numbers))
1,
2,
3
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, the * operator can be used also in combination with f-Strings

```
print(*(f'this is {x}' for x in [1,2,3]), sep='\n')

this is 1
this is 2
this is 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You get a list of `None` values because `print` function returns `None` and list comprehension uses the value of the expressions, not what is printed.

However, you can use the next code (with caution) to obtain the desired behavior inside the list comprehension:

```py
>>> [i for i in range(3) if print(i) or True]
0
1
2
[0, 1, 2]
```

The `i`-values are printed when is evaluated the `if` statement. This `if` guarantees call the `print` function and return `True`, so it doesn't discriminate values from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Alex Taylor gave the [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37084269/4539999).

> The `print` function returns `None`. The list comprehension is applying the function to each element of the list (outputting the results), but collecting those `None` objects into the results array. The Python interpreter is printing that array.

The `None` output can be consumed:

```py
>>> numbers = [1,2,3]
>>> _ = [print(x) for x in numbers]
1
2
3
>>> _
[None, None, None]
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

3 ways to print using list comps:

1. print outside

print([(i) or i for i in range(4)])

2. create a function

def printVal(val):
    print("val: ", val)
    return val

[printVal(i) or i for i in range(4)]

3. Use 'or'

[print(i) or i for i in range(4)]