# How to convert this code into python list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

```
for i in range(l):
   q = input()
   if(q not in array_num):
       print("NOT PRESENT")
   else:
       print(array_num.count(q))
```

i wrote below, but dont know where to use `q = input()`

```
[print("NOT PRESENT") if q not in array_num else print(array_num.count(q)) for i in range(l)]
```

Comment: *Why* do you need this to be with a list comprehension?

Comment: Using neat features is great and all, but the first code bit is readable, understandable, maintainable and clear. The other bit, not so much.

Comment: A list comprehension returns a `list`. Here you are printing out results on each iteration, so no point using it here.

Comment: I am just trying out if there is a situation like this can we write python comprehension?

Comment: list comprehension doesn't allow to assing value to variable - you would have to use `for q in [input()]` and then you can construct list comprehension - but it would create unreadable code.

Comment: While you can, I dont think it is good idea to use `input` within a list comprehension

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehensions for its side-effects is best avoided. See [Is it Pythonic to use list comprehensions for just side effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects) and [Printing using list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084246/printing-using-list-comprehension). That said, just for fun's sake, with Python3.8's [walrus operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/), you can accomplish this with

```
[print("NOT PRESENT") if (q:=input()) not in array_num else print(array_num.count(q)) for i in range(l)]
```

where the expression `q:=input()` will cause the return value of `input()` to be assigned to `q` and the value of the expression itself would become that of the new value of `q`.